# Getting input from client in python

Tags: python, function, sockets, parameter-passing

I am programming a client-server TCP connection in Python, and the client is asked to choose something from a list of functions, one of which is Fibonacci. So after the client picks Fibonacci I want him to be asked to enter a number, and that number to be sent to the Fibonacci function parameter and then return the value from the server to the client.

```
def FIBONACCI(n):
   if n == 0: return 0
   elif n == 1:  return 1
   else: return (FIBONACCI(n-1)+FIBONACCI(n-2))
```

I worked with functions without parameters and they work but I haven't seen anything with parameters.
Should the input be written in the client side and also how is it sent to the server and all that?
P.S I have sent the  input FIBONACCI with a sendall and I tried to do it again for the parameter but it doesn't seem to work... I hope I was clear.
This is how the function is called:

```
def requests (keyword):
   if (keyword == "FIBONACCI"):
   return FIBONACCI(n)
```

Comment: so the work flow is like **client:** input one integer, then send this integer to the server, finally wait until get the response from the server. **server:** receive integer from client, then calc Fibonacci, finally send back the result to the related client?

Comment: Yes exactly that, but first it gets the input Fibonacci from the client for the function to be called.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little chat program type between server and client.

This is `server.py`:

```
import socket;
import sys;
import thread;

try:
    s = socket.socket();
    port = 12345;
    s.bind(('', port));
    s.listen(5);
    i = 0;

    def main(c,numOfThread):
        while True:
            rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode();
            print "Thread:", numOfThread+1, "S:", rcvdData;
            sendData = raw_input("N: ");
            c.send(sendData.encode());
            if(sendData == "Bye" or sendData == "bye"):
                break;
        c.close();

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept();
        print "Socket Up and running with a connection from",addr;
        thread.start_new_thread(main,(c,i,));
        i+=1;

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nClosing Connection and freeing the port."
    c.close();
    sys.exit();
```

and this is `client.py`:

```
import socket;

try:
    s = socket.socket();
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1',12345));
    while True:
        str = raw_input("S: ");
        s.send(str.encode());
        if(str == "Bye" or str == "bye"):
            break;
        print "N:",s.recv(1024).decode();
    s.close();
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Closing Connection and freeing the port."
    s.close();
    sys.exit();
```

So as you can see just take the input from the client and then send it using `c.send(user_input)` and then similarly you can send the data from server to client. You can tweak this code to suit your need. Like in `server.py` you can add all your functions and then in `client.py` you can write the input statement like "Enter 1 for fibonacci 2 for addition .... and so on" take that input and send it to the server. Then in the server side just check that with what number the input matches and then call the following function.

You can also ask the user for the input of number before calling the function by sending a message to client about which function user has chosen and then the `client.py` will ask the user for input that which Fibonacci number he/she wants and then again send to the `server.py` and give that as an input to the function.

So basically the key here is `c.recv(1024)` and `s.send(user_input)`.